# PHP Look through file for specific line

Tags: php

I have a XML file looking like this

```
<table id="0">
</table>
<table id="1">
</table>
<table id="2">
</table>
```

I want to check if a table of id x exists

I have been trying this but does not work.

```
$file=fopen("config.xml","a+");
while (!feof($file))
  {
      if(fgets($file). "<br>" === '<table id="0">'){
        echo fgets($file). "<br>";
      }
  }
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Why are you using `'a+'` to open the file?  The `'a'` means *append*, so it puts the pointer at the end of the file.  Try with `$file=fopen("config.xml","r");`

Comment: Because later in the code I will be adding to the file aswell

Comment: @user2103723: Then use `r+`.  So you can read from the beginning, then shift it to where you want to write later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish that is using [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) class:

```
$html = file_get_html('file.xml');
$ret = $html->find('div[id=foo]');
```

[edit]
As for the code that does not work... Please notice that the xml you pasted does not have 
 characters so this string comparison will return false. If you want to take in consideration new line you should rather write `\n`... However the solution above is better because you don't have to get very strictly formated input file.

Comment: using this method how would I echo something if the ID was found?

Comment: @user2103723: Sounds like you want to do more than just find the `id`.  What are you aiming to do?  Far easier to process further data with it loaded in structurally like this.

Comment: I will make a new question, asking for what I am aiming to do, didnt think of my aproach not being the right one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DOMDocument class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), with XPath to find by ID, there is a [`getElementById()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) method, but it has issues.

```
// Setup sample data

$html =<<<EOT
<table id="0">
</table>
<table id="1">
</table>
<table id="2">
</table>
EOT;

$id = 3;

// Parse html
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// Alternatively you can load from a file
// $doc->loadHTMLFile($filename);

// Find the ID
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$table = $xpath->query("//*[@id='" . $id . "']")->item(0);

echo "Found: " . ($table ? 'yes' : 'no');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the file with mode `'a+'`.  The `'a'` means *append*, so it puts the pointer at the end of the file.

If you want to read the file, you probably want to start at the beginning, so use mode `'r'` (or `'r+'`).
<sub>Check the manual for the different file modes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php</sub>

Also, `fgets($file). "<br>" === '<table id="0">'` will *never* be true!  You are appending `<br>` to the string, and then comparing it to `<table id="0">` expecting it to match.

```
$file = fopen("config.xml", "r");
while (!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    if($line === '<table id="0">'){
        echo $line. "<br>";
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: would it be possible to later open it again with "a" to write to it?

Comment: @user2103723: Yeah.  Just make sure you only have one handle open for the file :-)

Comment: I do no get anything echoed using this method.

Comment: @user2103723: The lines may not compare exactly.  Try to `var_dump` each `$line` to see if there is any extra stuff on the line.

Comment: @user2103723: I'd actually prefer one of the other answers, using a DOM parser.  I just wanted to fix what was wrong with what you had.